# How do I tell KDE Konsole to open with a specified geometry and window title?

Tags: shell-script, terminal, konsole, kde5

I'm writing a script which needs to open a terminal window with a specific geometry and window title. I'm having trouble setting these with KDE konsole.

According to its help output I need to do:

```
  konsole -p <property=value>
```

and use

```
  konsole --list-profile-properties
```

to get a list of the available properties. So I did this and I found that the properties I want to change are:

```
   TerminalRows, TerminalColums, TerminalCenter and tabtitle.
```

Great. So I tried:

```
   konsole -p "TerminalRows=8"
```

but it didn't do anything. I've tried putting in all the properties like this but nothing seems to work. Did I mess up the syntax somehow? I should also note that I've installed console in gnome-shell in ubuntu, could that be what's giving me trouble?

Comment: "Configure Konsole>General>Use current window size on next startup must be disabled for these entries to work"

Comment: Ah, can that be disabled temporarily via terminal terminal or does it have to be unchecked by user?

Comment: Not sure, I just found that by looking at the option in the GUI.

Comment: Gnome has a command line tool called gsettings that allows you to set most of shell's prefs from the terminal. Do you know if kde has something similar? (thanks for tip by the way).

Comment: Yeah, check out `kwriteconfig`. I am not sure if it works for konsole settings, though.

Comment: `~/.config/konsolerc` appears to just be an INI file, which many languages have libraries for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't really seem possible due to a bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=147094

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the `konsole` command does not recognize the complete `-geometry ...` specification like `xterm`, e.g. `xterm -geometry 100x44+0-30`. You have to specify the window size separately. The following command is working:

```
konsole -p 'TerminalColumns=100' -p 'TerminalRows=42' -geometry +0-30
```

The additional parameter `-p 'LocalTabTitleFormat=my_tab'` gives you control over the tab title.

Comment: Copy-pasted that -- none of the switches did anything.  Until I followed jordanm's comment, *"Configure Konsole>General>Use current window size on next startup must be disabled for these entries to work"*.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `konsole --help-all` gave some additional QT options, one of which was `--qwindowgeometry` which does work.  However, the size params are pixel based, which is a bit less convenient.

It did allow setting of the window title with `--qwindowtitle title`; the -p option didn't work for the title property, maybe because it is focused on the tab.